# import ibm_db failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_db'

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to connect to ibm_db through python but it says the error

```
import ibm_db
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-fe3bb08c8a05>", line 1, in <module>
    import ibm_db

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_db'
```

As suggested in many other sites I tried to re-install using

`pip install ibm_db==2.0.8a` but that does not install either

```
import ibm_db
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-fe3bb08c8a05>", line 1, in <module>
    import ibm_db

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ibm_db'
```

I expect the `ibm_db` to get connected

db I am trying to connect is on the cloud

I am not sure if there is any setting I am missing here.

Any pointers or suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you have a *working* IBM Db2 Data server driver installed on your Windows Workstation?

Comment: Hi Mao, No Is it necessary even though I am trying to connect to DB2 on the cloud?? If yes, Could you please tell me how to install it

Comment: Yes it is necessary.  Which cloud service hosts your Db2-database? EDIT your question to add all the missing facts.

Answer (score 2):

What Python version are you using?

If you're using python 3 you should install it using `pip3`

```
pip3 install ibm_db==2.0.8a
```

Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks I tried that I got the error 

LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'db2cli.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181. I am using python 3

Comment: Are you able to install the package with this command? Or when you tried to run this, that's when the error occur?

Comment: Hi Rich, The above error occured when I tried this command pip3 install ibm_db==2.0.8a

Comment: Install the `pip3` first mate.

Comment: Hi Rich,I have installed pip3 yet I am getting the same error

fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'db2cli.lib' error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181

Comment: I tried to install the same version that you need and I am also getting an error. But When I tried to remove the `==2.0.8a` and install the latest version, I can install it without and problem. Do you really need that version?

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install ibm-db==3.0.1
```

here is the link: https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db/3.0.1/